# How can i get order product in an email body of crm 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have task to show a single order and to show its particular order line in an email template.
i have tried with workflows but still we cannot show order lines in an email body.

Please assist.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any idea about your code but it may help you to retrieve record as single record:

```
function retrieveAccount(AccountId) {
SDK.JQuery.retrieveRecord(
    AccountId, //Id of releated case

    "Account", //Entity name you want to get record to display
    null, null,
    function(account) {
        writeMessage("Retrieved the account named \"" + account.Name + "\". This account was created on : \"" + account.CreatedOn + "\".");
        updateAccount(AccountId);
    },
    errorHandler
);
}
```

This way you can get your desired record and can show anywhere in your file.

Answer (score 0):

I would go ahead by entering normal text in a `Email Template` with placeholders where you want the dynamic text to come in like

`Dear [ContactName], your Oder number is [OrderNumber]`

and create a custom workflow activity that will retrieve the required values and parse the email text, replace `[ContactName]` and `[OrderNumber]` with the actual values you want.

OR

Another possible way would be to create and send the email from the custom workflow activity itself using the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a [custom CodeActivity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328515.aspx) to retrieve the line items and format them. You can then insert the text block into the e-mail being generated by the Workflow.